# Compiling certain columns into a new array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

Let's say I have a 2D numpy array 'x' and I want to create a new array 'y' with only certain columns from x.

Is there an easy solution for this?

I was trying to write a function that iterates through each column of an array, and then appends every 3rd column to a new array.

```py
def grab_features(x, starting = 0, every = 3, rowlength = 16):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    y = np.empty([rowlength,1])
    for i in range(starting, np.size(x, 1), every):
        y = np.append(y, np.reshape(x[:, i], (rowlength, 1)), axis=0)

    return y
```

I didn't get any errors, but instead the function returned a long 1 dimensional array of float numbers. I was hoping for an array of the same type as x, just with 1/3 of the columns.

Comment: How are this certain columns selected? You could simply [slice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the slice syntax of `i:j:k` where `i` is the starting index, `j` is the stopping index, and `k` is the step size

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8],
                  [9,10],
                  [11,12]])
print(array[::3])
```

> [[1 2]
>   [7 8]]